# C# Как создать команду для бота

Tags: c#, бот

все никак не мог придумать название моей проблеме, думаю, сейчас тоже не особо вышло.
Пишу бота на C# для ВК используя библиотеку VKNet. На пример, есть такой код:

```
    else if (userMessage == ("/check"))
{
    // todo
}
```

Предположим, что команда /check проверяет некий баланс у человека в базе данных. Как мне сделать так, чтобы можно было ввести /check (имя), т.е. введенное имя должно записаться в строку отдельно от /check, проверку я уже сам реализую
Надеюсь, я смог понятно описать свою проблему (:

Comment: Используйте `.StartWith("/check")` и дальше работайте с этой строкой, удалив начало (команду).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если правильно понял суть вопроса, то можно просто взять подстроку начиная с 7го символа:

```
string s = "/check Shellar";
string name = s.Substring(7);
//name = "Shellar"
```